# Apache 2 authentication error

Tags: firefox, ssl, apache2, passenger, client-certificates

Attempting to implement client authentication with an SSL cert, according to [this HOWTO](http://www.modssl.org/docs/2.8/ssl_howto.html#auth-selective),
I receive the following errors.

Apache:

> Re-negotiation handshake failed: Not accepted by client!?

Firefox:

> ssl_error_handshake_failure_alert

I assume it is a configuration error, but have not been able to locate it.

Additional info:
Commercial CA server cert servers secure works without problem in Apache 2.2 & Passenger.
Only client authentication related directives do not work.

Comment: I'd think this question is more appropriate on ServerFault ( http://serverfault.com/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Is your certificate signed by verizon or someone like that? If not, you might want to add an exception in firefox. By default it stops you.

pd. doesn't sound like a passenger question

Answer (score 0):

When you require client certificate authorization, you have to point Apache to file containing the root CA (and intermediates also) certificates which **issued the client certificate**

Also post your client authentication config part.